# Using Gurobi to run a MIQP: how can I improve time performance?

Tags: matlab, optimization, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am using Gurobi to run a MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming) with linear constraints in Matlab. The solver is very slow and I would like your help to understand whether I can do something about it.

These are the lines which I use to launch the problem

```
clear model;
clear params;
model.A=[Aineq; Aeq];
model.rhs=[bineq; beq]; 
model.sense=[repmat('<', size(Aineq,1),1); repmat('=', size(Aeq,1),1)];
model.Q=Q;
model.obj=c;
model.vtype=type; 
model.lb=total_lb;
model.ub=total_ub;
params.MIPGap=10^(-1);
result=gurobi(model,params);
```

---

This is a screenshot of the output in the Matlab window. [image]

---

**Question 1:** It is the first time I am trying to run a MIQP and I would like to have your advice to understand what I can do to improve performance. Let me tell what I have tried so far:

- I cheated by imposing `params.MIPGap=10^(-1)`. In this way the phase of node exploration is made shorter. What are the cons of doing this?
- I have big-M coefficients and I have tied them to the smallest possible values.
- I have tried setting `params.ScaleFlag=2; params.ObjScale=2` but it makes things slower
- I have changed `params.method` but it does not seem to help (unless you have some specific recommendation)
- I have increase `params.Threads`  but it does not seem to help

**Question 2 (minor):** Why do I get a negative objective in the root simplex log? How can the objective function be negative?

Comment: Many MIQP models benefit from appropriate reformulations. If possible, linear reformulations are especially worthwhile to try out.

Comment: Thanks. I know little of optimization: what are linear reformulations of MIQP problems?

Comment: Could you point me to some useful reference on that? (for beginners)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about a general reference. Reformulations are very problem dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Without having the full model here, there is not much on advise to give. Tight Big-M formulations are important, but you said, you checked them already. Sometimes splitting them up might help, but this is a complex field.

What might give great benefits for *some* problems is using the [Gurobi parameter tuning tool](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/command_line_tuning.html). So try to export your model and feed the tuning tool with it. It automatically tries different of the hundreds of tuning parameters and might give some nice results.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question about negative objectives in the simplex logs,  I can think of a couple of possible explanations.   First, note that the negative objective values occur in the presence of dual infeasibilities in the dual simplex run. In such a case, I'm not sure exactly what the primal objective values correspond to.   Second, if you have a MIQP with products of binaries in the objective, Gurobi may convexify the objective in a way that makes it possible for a negative objective to appear in the reformulated model even when the original model must have a nonnegative objective in any feasible solution.